# main.js:95 WebSocket connection to 'wss://website' failed :(

Tags: javascript, django, webrtc

I have tried to make a simple video calling app using Django and WebRTC. I tried running this on localhost and it works well, but I tried hosting it on a website hosting platform and now it doesn't work. I surfed through many websites to correct this, but failed. I haven't used Redis server.

Here are some required files:

asgi.py

```
import os

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import chat.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myProject.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "https": get_asgi_application(),
    # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

settings.py

```
import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '****'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['https://myProject.herokuapp.com/']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chat',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myProject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myProject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/myProject/static/'


ASGI_APPLICATION = 'myProject.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [('https://myProject.herokuapp.com/'),
         ('redis://<my_secret_password_given_by_redislabs>@<my_redislabs_endpoint>')],
        },
    },
}
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

This is my **main.js** file that consists code for VideoCalling functionality.

```
console.log('in main.js')

var ICE_config = {
  'iceServers': [
    {
      'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    },
    {
      'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
      'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
      'username': '28224511:1379330808'
    },
    {
      'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
      'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
      'username': '28224511:1379330808'
    }
  ]
}

var mapPeers = {};
var usernameInput = document.querySelector('#username');
var btnJoin = document.querySelector('#btn-join');

var username;
var webSocket;

function webSocketOnMessage(event)
{
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(event.data);
    var peerUsername = parsedData['peer'];
    var action = parsedData['action'];

    if(username == peerUsername)
    {
        return;
    }
    var receiver_channel_name = parsedData['message']['receiver_channel_name'];

    if(action == 'new-peer'){
        createOfferer(peerUsername, receiver_channel_name);
        return;
    }

    if(action == 'new-offer'){
        var offer = parsedData['message']['sdp'];

        createAnswerer(offer, peerUsername, receiver_channel_name);
        return;
    }

    if(action == 'new-answer'){
        var answer = parsedData['message']['sdp'];

        var peer = mapPeers[peerUsername][0];

        peer.setRemoteDescription(answer);

        return;
    }

}

btnJoin.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    username= usernameInput.value;

    console.log(username);

    if(username =='')
    {
        return;
    }
    usernameInput.value='';
    usernameInput.disabled=true;
    usernameInput.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    btnJoin.disabled=true;
    btnJoin.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    var labelUsername = document.querySelector('#label-username');
    labelUsername.innerHTML = username;

    var loc = window.location;
    var wsStart = 'ws://';

    if(loc.protocol == 'https:')
    {
        wsStart = 'wss://';
    }

    var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname;

    console.log(endpoint);

line 95 --> webSocket = new WebSocket(endpoint);

    webSocket.addEventListener('open', (e) =>{
        console.log('Connection opened');

       sendSignal('new-peer',{});
    webSocket.addEventListener('message', webSocketOnMessage);
    webSocket.addEventListener('close', (e) =>{
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
    webSocket.addEventListener('error', (e) =>{
        console.log('Error occurred');
    });
});
});


var localStream = new MediaStream();

const constraints = {
    'video':true,
    'audio':true
}

const localVideo =  document.querySelector('#local-video');
const btnToggleAudio =  document.querySelector('#btn-toggle-audio');
const btnToggleVideo=  document.querySelector('#btn-toggle-video');

var userMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(stream => {
        localStream = stream;
        localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
        localVideo.muted = true;

        var audioTracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
        var videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();

        audioTracks[0].enabled = true;
        videoTracks[0].enabled = true;

        btnToggleAudio.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            audioTracks[0].enabled = !audioTracks[0].enabled;

            if(audioTracks[0].enabled){
                btnToggleAudio.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-microphone" style="font-size:20px;"></i>';
                return;
            }
            btnToggleAudio.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-microphone-slash" style="font-size:20px;"></i>';
        });
        btnToggleVideo.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            videoTracks[0].enabled = !videoTracks[0].enabled;

            if(videoTracks[0].enabled){
                btnToggleVideo.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-video" style="font-size:20px;"></i>';
                return;
            }
            btnToggleVideo.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-video-slash" style="font-size:20px;"></i>';
        });

    })
    .catch(error =>{
        console.log('Error accessing media devices!', error);
    });
    var btnSendMsg = document.querySelector('#btn-send-msg');
    var messageList = document.querySelector('#message-list');
    var messageInput = document.querySelector('#msg');
    btnSendMsg.addEventListener('click', sendMsgOnClick);

function sendMsgOnClick(){
    var message = messageInput.value;
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Me: '+ message));
    messageList.append(li);

    var dataChannels = getDataChannels();

    message = username + ': ' + message;

    for(index in dataChannels){
        dataChannels[index].send(message);
    }
    messageInput.value = '';
}

function sendSignal(action, message)
{

     var jsonStr = JSON.stringify({
           'peer': username,
           'action': action,
           'message': message,
         });
     webSocket.send(jsonStr);
}

function createOfferer(peerUsername, receiver_channel_name)
{
    
    var peer = new RTCPeerConnection(ICE_config);
    addLocalTracks(peer);

    var dc = peer.createDataChannel('channel');
    dc.addEventListener('open',() =>{
        console.log('Connection opened!');
    });
    dc.addEventListener('message', dcOnMessage);

    var remoteVideo = createVideo(peerUsername);
    setOnTrack(peer, remoteVideo);

    mapPeers[peerUsername] = [peer,dc];

    peer.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', ()=>{
        var iceConnectionState = peer.iceConnectionState;
        if(iceConnectionState === 'failed'|| iceConnectionState === 'disconnected' || iceConnectionState === 'closed'){
            delete mapPeers[peerUsername];
            if(iceConnectionState != 'closed')
            {
                peer.close();
            }
            removeVideo(remoteVideo);
        }
    });
    peer.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event)=>{
        if(event.candidate){
            console.log('New ice candidate', JSON.stringify(peer.localDescription));
            return;
        }
        sendSignal('new-offer',{
            'sdp' : peer.localDescription,
            'receiver_channel_name': receiver_channel_name

        });

    });
    peer.createOffer()
        .then(o => peer.setLocalDescription(o))
        .then(() =>{
            console.log('Local description set successfully');
        });

}


function addLocalTracks(peer){
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        peer.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });
    return;
}


function dcOnMessage(event){
    var message = event.data;

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    messageList.appendChild(li);
}


function createAnswerer(offer, peerUsername, receiver_channel_name)
{
    var peer = new RTCPeerConnection(ICE_config);
    addLocalTracks(peer);

    var remoteVideo = createVideo(peerUsername);
    setOnTrack(peer, remoteVideo);

    peer.addEventListener('datachannel', e => {
        peer.dc = e.channel;
        peer.dc.addEventListener('open',() => {
            console.log('Connection opened!');
        });
    peer.dc.addEventListener('message', dcOnMessage);
    mapPeers[peerUsername] = [peer,peer.dc];

    });


    peer.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', () => {
        var iceConnectionState = peer.iceConnectionState;
        if(iceConnectionState === 'failed'|| iceConnectionState === 'disconnected' || iceConnectionState === 'closed'){
            delete mapPeers[peerUsername];
            if(iceConnectionState != 'closed')
            {
                peer.close();
            }
            removeVideo(remoteVideo);
        }
    });
    peer.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event) => {
        if(event.candidate){
            console.log('New ice candidate', JSON.stringify(peer.localDescription));
            return;
        }
        sendSignal('new-answer',{
            'sdp' : peer.localDescription,
            'receiver_channel_name': receiver_channel_name

        });

    });
    peer.setRemoteDescription(offer)
        .then(() =>{
            console.log('Remote Description set successfully for %s.', peerUsername);

            return peer.createAnswer();
        })
        .then(a =>{
            console.log('Answer created!');
            peer.setLocalDescription(a);
        });
}


function createVideo(peerUsername){
    var videoContainer = document.querySelector('#video-container');
    var remoteVideo = document.createElement('video');
    remoteVideo.id = peerUsername + '-video';
    remoteVideo.autoplay = true;
    remoteVideo.playsInline = true;

    var videoWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    videoContainer.appendChild(videoWrapper);
    videoWrapper.appendChild(remoteVideo);
    return remoteVideo;
}

function setOnTrack(peer, remoteVideo){
    var remoteStream = new MediaStream()

    remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
    peer.addEventListener('track', async(event) =>{
        remoteStream.addTrack(event.track, remoteStream);
    });
}

function removeVideo(video){
    var videoWrapper = video.parentNode;
    videoWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(videoWrapper);
}

function getDataChannels(){
    var dataChannels =[];

    for(peerUsername in mapPeers){
        var dataChannel = mapPeers[peerUsername][1];

        dataChannels.push(dataChannel);
    }

    return dataChannels;
}
```

I'm also attaching **main.html** for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TClone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li>
                        <div style="float:right;" class="nav-link">
                            <button class="bg-dark" id="btn-toggle-audio"><i class="fas fa-microphone" style="font-size:20px;"></i></button>
                            <button class="bg-dark" id="btn-toggle-video"><i class="fas fa-video" style="font-size:20px;"></i></button>
                            <button class="bg-dark" id="main" onclick="openNav()"><i class="far fa-comments" style="font-size:20px;"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                </div>
        </nav>
<h3 id="label-username">USERNAME</h3>
<div>
    <input id="username"><button id="btn-join" class="bg-dark">Join Room</button>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="video-container">

        <div>
            <video id="local-video" style="float:left;" poster="{% static 'images/profile.png' %}" controls  width="590px" height="480px" autoplay playsinline></video>
        </div>

    </div>
        <div class="sidenav bg-dark" id="mySidebar">
            <h3 style="color:white">CHAT</h3>
             <button class="closebtn bg-dark"">×</button>

            <div id="messages">
                <ul id="message-list" class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="msg"><button id="btn-send-msg" class="bg-dark">Send Message</button>
            </div>
            <button id="btn-share-screen" class="bg-dark">Share screen</button>
        </div>
</div>

<script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***EDIT:***

**consumers.py**

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer


class ChatConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'Test-Room'

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        print('Disconnected')

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        receive_dict = json.loads(text_data)
        message = receive_dict['message']
        action = receive_dict['action']

        if (action == 'new-offer') or (action == 'new-answer'):
            receiver_channel_name = receive_dict['message']['receiver_channel_name']
            receive_dict['message']['receiver_channel_name'] = self.channel_name
            await self.channel_layer.send(
                receiver_channel_name,
                {
                    'type': 'send.sdp',
                    'receive_dict': receive_dict
                }
            )
            return

        receive_dict['message']['receiver_channel_name'] = self.channel_name

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'send.sdp',
                'receive_dict': receive_dict
            }
        )

    async def send_sdp(self, event):
        receive_dict = event['receive_dict']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(receive_dict))
```

Also adding **Procfile**.

```
web: gunicorn myProject.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py migrate
worker: python manage.py runworker channel_layer
web: python myProject/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

**requirements.txt**

```
django

django-channels

gunicorn

django_heroku
```

And when I run this app, I get this error:

***in main.js line 95:WebSocket connection to 'wss://(name of website).com/' failed:***

I tried checking the security of the website hosting service, and it is https. Now I am really NOT able to identify where my error is and I really need help in correcting this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey did you found a solution yet?

Comment: No...I have used Heroku for the deployment, but the issue still persists.
I really need help in correcting this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure what have you done wrong in your code and if this will help. But let's try something. First, in the ```INSTALLED_APPS```, move ```channels``` to the top. Second, you are not supposed to use ```InMemoryChannelLayer``` in production. So use ```channels_redis``` and use Heroku's Redis Add-on. Try these and let me know if it works.

Comment: Is there any way to get free Redis add-on since it requires credit card info for processing?

Comment: You can use [RedisLabs](https://redislabs.com/try-free/). This is how you will configure it: ```CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts" : [('redis://:<your_secret_password_given_by_redislabs>@<your_redislabs_endpoint>')],
        },
    },
}```

Comment: Hello! I had tried what you have said, i.e. used RedisLabs and changed channel_layers from inmemorychannellayer to redischannellayer. But the issue still persists. May I know the reason?
Am I missing something in requirements.txt or Procfile?
Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: It's very hard to tell what are you missing. Please provide your ```asgi.py```, ```consumers.py```, ```Procfile```.

Comment: Sure!
I'll add them

Comment: I think I found the solution. I have added an answer. Check it out and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `Procfile`. `Gunicorn` is a WSGI HTTP Server. It doesn't support ASGI. This is what you have to do.

But first things first, in `requirements.txt` that's not how you're supposed to add packages. Create a virtual environment(if you haven't already) with either by `pipenv`, `virtualenv` or if you don't want to download additional packages, then you can use `venv`. (**Note: There is no major difference among the three mentioned packages.**).

In your working directory, run this on the root level of your `django-channels` project: `python -m venv venv`. Then activate the `venv`:

`venv\Scripts\activate` - if you are on Windows

`source venv/bin/activate` - if you are on Mac or Linux.

Then install `django`, `channels`, `channels_redis` with `pip`.

Now run: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. This will add all the required packages correctly.

**Now,** in your `Procfile` delete everything and add these lines:

```
web: daphne <your_project>.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channels --settings=<your_project>.settings -v2
```

Deploy again with these settings.

**EDIT:**

Change your `Procfile` to this:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: daphne <your_project>.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channels --settings=<your_project>.settings -v2
```

And I see that you have changed your Redis configuration to this:

```
"CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [('https://myProject.herokuapp.com/'), // <--- I don't think this line is necessary, so change it back to what it was
         ('redis://<my_secret_password_given_by_redislabs>@<my_redislabs_endpoint>')],
        },
```

Comment: Hi...Thank you so much for your help!
But now I get these errors after I followed the steps mentioned:

1. python: can't open file '/app/manage.py'

2. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myProject.asgi'

After which my app crashes. And now I don't see any page of my app, instead I see 'Application Error' page of Heroku :((
May I know the reason for this?

Comment: I have made some edits. Check now. And as per your second problem, are you sure that you have given the correct name of the ```project```? Can you provide the folder structure of your project?

Comment: Also, now it gives me same error even on localhost, although it worked before I made these changes. What am I supposed to be doing now asince my basic peer-to-peer connection is also not working?

Comment: What error are you getting on ```localhost```?

Comment: No folder structure means a list of all the files and folders you have in that project. You can provide a screenshot or something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUflg.png)

Comment: On localhost, I get ws://connection failed...Till now it worked well...I have no clue why is that getting changed now

Comment: This could take days so what I would suggest is that you upload your project to Github(if you haven't already) and give me the link to your repository.

Comment: Even I felt that's easier..
I'll add u as colab..pls share ur github ID..:)

Comment: ```ayushgupta0010```

Comment: Added you as collab

Comment: I believe you were trying to deploy the project on Azure but you are not doing that now. So may I delete the ```.github/workflows``` folder??

Comment: Would that affect in anyway? Coz the deployment is not really successful on Azure either..so I'm trying on both..

Comment: I will try to make the deployment successful on Heroku. If that doesn't work then you would already have that folder in your computer you could use to deploy to Azure.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Right now, as I said, even localhost has some issues...so I'm trying to resolve it as I really didn't make much changes except for collecting requirements.txt on localhost, yet it fails to connect all of sudden.

Comment: Hey, I have made a commit and something still doesn't work.  This can only be detected on Heroku. Open your Heroku account and check what is the error in deployment. **And now it is working on  localhost**

Comment: It was the error in requirements.txt
Do remove twisted-iocpsupport and keep only twisted in requirements.txt
Few are actually unnecessary in fact

Comment: No, they are added while installing django, channels, channels_redis and whitenoise. It's better not to mess with them. Wait let me try something else.

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

This is the error after changing...just check the core file once

Build succeeded but application error

Comment: Can you give me the detailed error? or collaborate with me on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use daphne.

https://github.com/django/daphne

I will try to show you the minimum configuration.

```
app
├── app
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── main
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── routing.py
│   ├── consumers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── templates
│       │
│       └── chat
│            └── room.html
├── manage.py
```

asgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')
import django
django.setup()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import main.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            main.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
import main.consumers
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"ws/chat/(?P<root_name>\w+)/$", main.consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer): 
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name  = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["room_name"]
        self.room_group_name = "chat_%s" % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        print("receive")
```

settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'main.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

views.py

```
def room(request, room_name):
    return render(request, "chat/room.html", {"room_name": room_name})
```

room.html

```
{{ room_name|json_script:"roomName" }}
<script>
    roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("roomName").textContent);
        chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            "ws://"
            + window.location.host
            + "/ws/chat/"
            + roomName
            + "/"
        );
</script>
```

Run

```
~/app$ daphne app.asgi:application
```

Open

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/room_1/
```